# Question about proof of n-th orthogonal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the book of Abstract Algebra I'm seeing there is an example of a group, $Ort_n(\mathbb{R})$ which is the group of all orthogonal endomorphisms in $\mathbb{R^n}$, all endomorphisms $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $||f(u)|| = ||u||$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R^n}$ with the operation composition.

When proving that this indeed is a group, in order to show that $f \in \mathbb{R^n}$ has an inverse in $Ort_n(\mathbb{R})$ the book proves that every $f$ is one-to-one, therefore it's an isomorphism, and then proves that it is surjective.

---

I don't understand why does $f$ being one-to-one imply that it is an isomorphism, and neither understand the proof of surjectivity. Any hints?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Since you are in finite dimension, the dimension of the kernel of an endomorphism and the dimension of the image of the endomorphism sum to the dimension of the domain space ($n$, here). So if your endomorphism is one-to-one, its range is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n$, so it is $\mathbb{R}^n$ in full, ie your endomorphism is surjective.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(u)=0$ implies that $\|f(u)\|=\|u\|=0$ $Ker f=0$ since $f$ is linear it is injective. An injective linear map between finite dimensional vector space which have the same dimension is surjective and therefore bijective.

Comment: Seems obvious now, thanks!!! I need 5 minutes in order to accept your answer...